# Does Redhat and CentOS come with zlib preinstalled?

Tags: centos, rhel, python, compression

Does Redhat and CentOS come with zlib preinstalled?

If yes, which versions have it?

// need to know if I can expect users to have it on their Servers, since I can't install it there, and can't ask them to do it

I'm trying to use Python's zipfile library. To make it actually compress given files I have to pass a ZIP_DEFLATED flag. And the documentation says:

```
if ZIP_DEFLATED is specified but the zlib module is not available, RuntimeError is also raised.
```

Tags didn't take zlib at first that's why I put zip and gzip

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont see a package called zlip in CentOS 6 or 7. Also no pre-installed package with that name. Can you confirm the package name ?

Comment: you've tagged zip and gzip - did you mean one of those?

Comment: Please see my edits in the post about Python zipfile library

Comment: The confusion was because of the 'p' instead of a 'b' in zlip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `zlib`, which would be a yes, but if you mean `zlib-devel` (because you need to compile something), then no.

Comment: Yes, zlib only (see my edits in the post about Python zipfile library). thanks

Comment: to be precise, if only Redhat 5 and up support it that would be good enough.

Comment: Zlib is quite a generically used library, most default installs of any distro will have it, even windows depends on it :) the Python zlib module is part of the standard library and should be available as well, although slightly less sure than zlib proper.